# Count SQL table row and add 1 on the outcome

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to count a table row and add 1 on the outcome, I have this snippet of code.

```
$countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM donations";
$outcomeQuery = mysql_query($countQuery);
$countUp = mysql_fetch_array($outcomeQuery);
$plusOne = 1; 
$outcome = $countUp;
echo $outcome[0]
    or die(mysql_error());
```

But this gives me the error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

I need this so I always have a unique number that's not used by a previous donator.

Comment: Note this will not always be guaranteed unique if it runs twice at the same time.

Comment: NB. Count(ID) is not the same as Max(ID), and your SQL platform probably has a better way to find the next ID.

Comment: @Ic. I know, but I'll use 4 random generated numbers to make 100% sure there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use simple php

```
$countQuery = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM donations");
$count=mysql_num_rows($countQuery);
$count+=1;
```

Comment: What happens when another row is inserted between the first read and the write that uses the `$count` variable that you pick up here?

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)+1 as IDCount FROM donations
```

as your query instead. This will save you any mucking about in PHP to do the math. The array you pull back will have the number that you want right off the bat.

Edit: The better alternative however is to use a column type that increments automatically. In MySQL, this is done with the syntax `auto_increment` in the create table syntax.

Using this, you never actually *have* to insert a value, but rather, you pass it a `NULL` as follows (assuming that ID is the field with Auto_increment on it:

```
insert into tableName (ID,Name) values (null, 'Fluffeh');
```

So you see you don't give it any values for the ID column - the database takes care of using the right number.

Comment: Doing calculations in the query is always better and faster.

Comment: @Quasarthespacething Yeah, I was making an edit as the comment popped up. The edit I think covers the comment you were addressing :)

Comment: I tried doing this and couldn't get it to work, for some reason it's stuck at "1".

Comment: @Laetificat You probably used the wrong column name to address it. Be careful with using the code in the accepted answer as it can go awry when two users use the script at the same time.

Comment: @Fluffeh That wouldn't be a problem because it also generates a 11 character long random string before it, this extra count is just to be 1000% sure it's unique in case the same string is generated twice by coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

It's dangerous to rely on **`COUNT`** to give you a unique number. What happens if two processes execute this query, and then both try and commit: you suddenly have the same value twice.

It would be much safer to implement some kind of sequence function independent of your table contents. This link shows one possibility:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,143867,238482#msg-238482

Comment: I will use random generated numbers too, but it's easy to make sure there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This question is for a MySQL database.  I suggest you use the [AUTO INCREMENT field type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html).
As you are using PHP, if you need to know the id after inserting a record, use:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (1, 2, 3, 'blah')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

See [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Using

> 4 random generated numbers to make 100% sure there are no duplicates

will not make 100% sure there are no duplicates. Don't re-invent the wheel.  This is how the problem of ensuring unique incrementing identifiers are used has been solved, you don't need the embarrassment of a homebrew solution that doesn't always work.